# Create SharePoint CAML recurring calendar item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I'm using the Lists.asmx webservices to connect to my SharePoint 2010 server.  I can upload a new calendar item using the below XML, but I can't figure out what field to add so that it's a "recurring every weekday" instead of an event that spans multiple days.

```xml
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" ViewName="">  
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">  
    <Field Name="Title">Test Event</Field>  
    <Field Name="EventDate">2018-10-01 00:00:00</Field>  
    <Field Name="EndDate">2018-10-01 23:59:59</Field>
    <Field Name="fAllDayEvent">1</Field>
    <Field Name="fRecurrence">1</Field>
    <Field Name="EventType">1</Field>
    <Field Name="UID">{17ea5230-d1f4-4fe2-acc2-450e839998ee}</Field>
    <Field Name="RecurrenceData"><![CDATA[<recurrence>
  <rule>
    <firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek>
    <repeat>
      <weekly mo="TRUE" tu="TRUE" we="TRUE" th="TRUE" fr="TRUE" weekFrequency="1" />
    </repeat>
    <repeatInstances>10</repeatInstances>
  </rule>
</recurrence>]]></Field>
  </Method>
</Batch>
```

I'm creating the code as shown in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/grosch/d05f0684b9621fa83444fcce1f45929d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to include two additional parameters are part of your event creation - one to let SharePoint know it is a recurring event (fRecurrence, a Boolean value) and another with the actual recurrence pattern (RecurrenceData, an XML string).

You can read more about the structure of the RecurrenceData XML here:
http://thehightechheels.blogspot.com/2012/12/sharepoint-evenet-recurrencedata-xml.html

There's quite a bit to it so rather than re-stating everything there, I'll share an example of how to create an event that recurs each weekday as requested:

```
<recurrence>
    <rule>
        <firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek>
        <repeat>
            <weekly mo="TRUE" tu="TRUE" we="TRUE" th="TRUE" fr="TRUE" weekFrequency="1" />
        </repeat>
        <repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever>
    </rule>
</recurrence>
```

Generally speaking a recurrence rule has 3 parts: the day of the week considered the first day; the pattern for repeating the event, and; when it ends, which can be never, after '*n*' occurrences or by a certain calendar date.

Within the `<repeat>` section is where you have a lot of flexibility to set the pattern. For your scenario, the use of the `<weekly>` element combined with the `weekFrequency` parameter ensures this event will repeat every week. Within that week, we can then set which days of the week are to include the event; by setting Monday through Friday to "TRUE" (`mo`, `tu`, `we`, `th`, `fr`) we're telling SharePoint to repeat the event each of those days.

Summarizing the full Batch XML changes discussed in the comments below, here is the input I've used on my local SP2010 environment:

```
<Batch OnError="Return">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">  
        <Field Name="Title">Test Event</Field>  
        <Field Name="EventDate">2018-10-01 00:00:00</Field>  
        <Field Name="EndDate">2018-10-01 23:59:59</Field>
        <Field Name="fAllDayEvent">1</Field>
        <Field Name="fRecurrence">1</Field>
        <Field Name="EventType">1</Field>
        <Field Name="Duration">86340</Field>
        <Field Name="WorkspaceLink">0</Field>
        <Field Name="TimeZone">0</Field>
        <Field Name="UID">{17ea5230-d1f4-4fe2-acc2-450e839998ee}</Field>
        <Field Name="RecurrenceData"><![CDATA[
<recurrence>
    <rule>
        <firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek>
        <repeat>
            <daily weekday="TRUE" />
        </repeat>
        <repeatInstances>7</repeatInstances>
    </rule>
</recurrence>]]>
        </Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

Which yields this:
[image]

Comment: I tried that but it's still not working.  I updated my question to show the exact XML I'm sending.  The Sharepoint returns error 0, i.e. good, but when I open the calendar item I get a red error saying that "root element missing" and then a UID for the event that I Just created.

Comment: The recurrence data needs to be an XML *string*, not an XML object.

Comment: LOL.  OK, much closer now.  Set it to a string, and now it appears properly in the calendar view.  When I click on the item though, sharepoint pops up a window saying: Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Comment: In your updated sample XML you appear to have dropped/lost the `<repeat>` element shown in my answer. That's a require element in the recurrence XML string and should be wrapping your `<weekly.../>` element.

Comment: Also, depending on how you're executing your call, you may need to wrap the recurrence XML in a CDATA tag (`<![CDATA[<recurrence>...</recurrence>]]>`). I just tested a fixed version of your XML though and was able to successfully create a recurring item.

Comment: Last comment - I see your item create XML is also missing the `UID` field, which is required when creating recurring events. The UID just needs to be set to a randomly-generated GUID value (e.g. `System.Guid.NewGuid();`).

Comment: Thanks.  I made the changes, and updated my XML.  I'm assuming I put the UID where you meant.  Unfortunately it seems IT took down my sharepoint site until 10pm tonight, so I'll test it at that point.  Thank you for the continued guidance!

Comment: Yes, that looks better - just make sure the UID is always unique ;)

Comment: One small note - the UID should be wrapped in curly brackets {...}

Comment: Still the same issue.  It shows up in the calendar, but if I click on it I get the error saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: I added a link to a gist showing the C# code I'm using to create the item.

Comment: Looking at a currently functioning example in my SP2010 environment, the only other thing I see in my Batch XML is `WorkspaceLink` and `TimeZone` elements, both set to 0 (zero). I didn't believe those to be mandatory but perhaps see if adding them with those values helps. EDIT: Looks like you're missing `Duration` as well; for an all day event, that should be set to 86340, which in seconds equates to 23 hrs, 59 mins (the standard for an All-day Event in SP).

Comment: The key is TimeZone.  After much back and forth with a Microsoft support case it was determined that TimeZone set to 0 is in fact the key element.  I also switched to the newer recurrence that you used as well, where we just say daily with a weekday=TRUE attribute.  Much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it easier on anyone else who finds this, here's the complete C# code necessary to create a recurring element.

```csharp
 private static XDocument GenerateBatchInsertXML(string title, DateTime start, DateTime end)
 {  
     // http://thehightechheels.blogspot.com/2012/12/sharepoint-evenet-recurrencedata-xml.html
     var recurrence = new XElement("recurrence",
                             new XElement("rule",
                                 new XElement("firstDayOfWeek", "su"),
                                 new XElement("repeat",
                                     new XElement("daily",
                                         new XAttribute("weekday", "TRUE"))),
                                 new XElement("windowEnd", String.Format("{0:o}", end))));

     return new XDocument(
        new XElement("Batch",
         new XAttribute("OnError", "Continue"),
         new XAttribute("DateInUtc", "True"),
         new XElement("Method",
           new XAttribute("ID", "1"),
           new XAttribute("Cmd", "New"),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "Title"), title),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "EventDate"), String.Format("{0:o}", start)),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "EndDate"), String.Format("{0:o}", end)),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "fAllDayEvent"), "1"),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "fRecurrence"), "1"),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "EventType"), "1"),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "UID"), "{" + Guid.NewGuid() + "}"),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "TimeZone"), "0"),
           new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name", "RecurrenceData"),
             new XCData(recurrence.ToString())))));
 }
```